# Save whitespace from two-column list

Tags: html, css, whitespace, html-lists

I'm trying to recreate a table behaviour, where I have two columns, after a line-break of the 2nd column, it should save the space from the first column. **Without** adding  definitive values of width or padding/margin.

**edit:** To clear things up. This is exactly the behaviour I want, I don't know why it's so hard for a list to recreate: http://jsfiddle.net/tLtLM/1/

```
<ul class="hobby-list">
   <li class="first-column">Hobbies:</li>
   <li><span>Entry, entry, entry, entry, entry, entry, entry, entry, entry</span></li>
</ul>

.hobby-list li{
display:inline;
height:100%;
}

li.first-column{
height:100%; 
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsJpK.png

Comment: Did you try using &nbsp; instead of simply hitting "space"?

Comment: Well I want to to break if the line is too long. And if it breaks preserve the whitespace of the first column. With non-breaking spaces I would always have a long line.

Comment: What browsers do you want to support?

Comment: Any new browser is fine, but I'm having a fluid layout - so anything with fixed width is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) which is currently a working draft:

```
.hobby-list {
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
}

.hobby-list li + li {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;  
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;  
    box-flex: 1; 
}
```

See [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) for browser support information. For browsers that don't support flexbox you could use something like this:

```
.hobby-list {
    display: table-row;
}

.hobby-list li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: That looks really good. Thanks for providing the support information, no IE 9 support is a real bummer though. I might just use your 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

Use your HTML with this...

CSS:

```
.hobby-list li
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.hobby-list li:nth-child(1)
{
    width:80px;
}
.hobby-list li:nth-child(2)
{
    width:210px;
}
```

Comment: It's coming close, but this is still not scalable with the hard values of width. I might just use the good old table, http://jsfiddle.net/tLtLM/1/